# On the angle of a polar decomposition of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, unitary-matrices, hermitian-matrices

Let $A\in\mathbb{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$. $A$ is non-singular. Then $A=UR$ where $U$ is a unitary matrix, and $R$ is a positive-semidefinite Hermitian matrix. I understand the intuition that this is analogous to $U$ encoding some $\theta$ and $R$ encoding the modulus/radius $r$, taking the complex plane in polar coordinates. I have seen it confidently written that $|A|=|U|\cdot|R|=\exp(i\theta)\cdot r$. Intuitively, by the definition above, this should make sense, since any unit square/cube/etc. would be rotated and scaled under $A$, and this determinant agrees with that. However, being more formal, I wonder how a person might prove this, or find $\theta.$

$|\exp(A)|=\exp(tr(A))$, and also any unitary $U=\exp(iH)$, where $H$ is Hermitian. Therefore $|U|=|\exp(iH)|=\exp(tr(iH))=\exp(i\cdot tr(H))$. If $|U|$ is to be $\exp(i\theta)$, then the mystery $H$ must have a trace equal to $\theta$. Is this correct?

As a complete side-question from the main focus of this post, is the finding of $H$ a messy problem almost always left to computers - can the trace=$\theta$ idea be leveraged for this? And when Wikipedia mentioned $U=\exp(iH)$, did they mention it out of trivia, or because of some utility, some application of this fact?

Comment: +1 Interesting question, but I doubt there is an answer that is elementary, exact, and avoids the logarithm. It wouldn't be reasonable to ask, for example, what for the $\theta$ in $re^{i\theta} = 6 - 37i$ without using inverse trig functions or numerical approximation.

Comment: @TheoBendit Ok. Leaving the $H$-finding aside, is my idea about $tr(H)=\theta$ correct?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what $\theta$ refers to, unless it's to $H$. In four dimensions, $H$ could be a composition of two independent (and commuting) rotations by two different angles in two different planes. It isn't clear to me how you extract a single number $\theta$, unless it's the perfectly reasonable method you propose.

Comment: there's a lot of problems with uniqueness since the complex exponential is not injective.  I think you mean equality of $\theta$ up to a multiple of $2\pi i$.  Same idea with finding "the H".

Comment: @TheoBendit This nebulous idea of "$\theta$" is ripped from the Wikipedia article on polar decomposition which just states "$|U|=\exp(i\theta)$" without context or proof, so I did some thinking on my own and came up with the above question... you make a good point about higher dimensions - perhaps I should only consider this odd $|U|=\exp(i\theta)$ in two dimensions

Comment: @user8675309 Sure, I appreciate that. What I am really getting at with that side-question is: computers are excellent and well-versed in finding LU and QR decompositions and I assume plenty of other decompositions out there - are they able to find this $U=\exp(iH)$ and of course any equivalent with the periodicity of $\exp$, and could they be motivated to do so?

Comment: @IdioticShrike In $5$ dimensions, the same problem persists: you can still take the composition of two independent simple rotations, and leave a fifth dimension fixed. The point is, there's a reason we need to encode the information in an entire matrix, not just a single number (as we can in the $2$-dimension case).